# Is Conjunctive Normal Form or not?

Tags: algorithms, terminology, logic, propositional-logic, normal-forms

I have one formula that I do not understand why it is CNF and one that is not CNF, namely.

1. p && !q (NOT NCF)

and

2. !!p(CNF).

According to the exercise where I found these examples, 1 is not CNF and 2 is CNF.

How can the first formula not be CNF, when for example p && q is CNF.
If for example !!p is part of a formula we will translate it to p, how can we say that it is CNF?

Answer (score 1):

Your examples do not look correct according to my understanding of the definition of CNF.  The first formula is CNF; it has two clauses, each with a single literal.  I would say that the second isn't, but the equivalent formula p is.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjunctive_normal_form.

Comment: Yes, that was exactly my thought! This was just some exercise and I could not understand how the examples above could be correct. Will update my question..